# Where can I ask questions about failed tests when compiling PHP?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I compiled PHP and compilation went fine (no errors). On the `make test` step I get one test that doesn’t pass. Should I ignore it since the compilation went right anyway or should I do something about it?

Relevant test output is:

```
=====================================================================
FAILED TEST SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
bool checkdnsrr ( string $host [, string $type = "MX" ] ); [ext/standard/tests/checkdnsrr.phpt]
=====================================================================
```

The following communities don’t seem to fit:

- Stack Overflow is for programming questions
- Server Fault is for sys-admin stuff, I guess
- Unix & Linux is for sys-admin stuff for Unix-like OSes
- Super User is for help with apps or userland OS questions.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is clearly a progrmming problem.

Comment: Yup, Stack Overflow is the site to go. I do not know all that much about PHP, but you might want to add your code to the question as well before posting it on there (unless that output can stand on its own, in which case its fine as is).

Comment: I haven't written a single line of code I think the question is misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow is the place to go. It is about code, a compiler and a code testing framework. Had to see it is not about programming. It is the basics of programming.

If you'd post a question there, make sure to include:

- Code;
- A clear problem statement;
- Compiler/IDE versions;
- Your own attempts in finding a solution.

If you do so, the question will be well-received.

Comment: I have not written a single line of code. I'm just trying to compile PHP 7.2.9 on my server.

Comment: @ychaouche I misunderstood you then, my bad. Nonetheless Stack Overflow is the place to go when it comes to these type of questions as well.

Comment: Compiling PHP is still compiling code. @ychaouche

Answer (score 1):

Even though you haven't written any code here yourself, this still seems like a clear code-ish problem. The solution will be some code-ish solution -- things like attempting to reinstall, update packages, change environment variables, and debug the test.

- Stack Overflow is the biggest catch-all for questions like this, and this will be firmly on topic there. You're trying to install a coding tool, installation has some kind of problem or bug. You're cool.
- If you're on Unix/Linux, then Unix &Linux have many questions on setup and tool installation; this would be on topic there.
- Super User might technically be relevant because this is about installing and using tools. But Stack Overflow feels more "on target" to me.